# JavaScript to Validate Form if certain selections are made and show dialog box

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML form which has 3 sections of yes/no questions for the user to complete. There's an existing script to ensure they only select answers to one of the 3 sections.

I would now like to add an additional validation for when the user selects no for all the answers in any section. If they do select no for the section questions I would like to throw a dialog box with 2 buttons (OK and Cancel) and text "You have selected No for your answers. Do you wish to continue?"

Here's my form and the current scripts I have:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#editRecord").on("submit", function(e) {
    var buttonClicked = $("input[type=submit][clicked=true]").val();

    if (buttonClicked === "Continue") {
      if (!validateFinish(e)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Continue");
      }
    } else if (buttonClicked === "Save Draft") {
      if (!validateSaveDraft()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Save Draft");
      }
    }
  });

  $("input[type=submit]").click(function() {
    $("input[type=submit]", $(this).parents("form")).removeAttr("clicked");
    $(this).attr("clicked", "true");
  });

  function validateFinish(ev) {
    // Add your validation logic for the Finish button here
    //alert("Form Validation is starting!");

    var sectionsTouched = $('tbody').has(':checked'),
      inputs = {},
      errorMessage = '';

    if (sectionsTouched.length === 0) {
      errorMessage = 'Please check something before submitting.';
    } else if (sectionsTouched.length > 1) {
      errorMessage = 'Please complete A or B or C only';
    } else {
      sectionsTouched.find('input').each(function(i, e) {
        var me = $(e),
          name = me.attr('name');
        inputs[name] = !!inputs[name] || me.is(':checked');
      });
      $.each(inputs, function(k, v) {
        if (!v) {
          errorMessage = 'It appears you have not completed all questions.';
        }
        return v;
      });
    }
    if (errorMessage !== '') {
      $('#error').html(errorMessage);
      ev.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  function validateSaveDraft() {
    // Add your validation logic for the Save Draft button here
    //alert("Just saving a Draft!");
    return true;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="rateArticleCodes.php" method="post" class="" id="editRecord">
  <input type="hidden" name="recid" value="123445">


  <div class="rate-buttons left py2">
    <input type="submit" name="buttonType" id="saveDraft" value="Save Draft" class="mr1">
    <input type="reset" name="buttonType" value="Reset" class="mx1">
    <input type="submit" name="buttonType" id="submit" value="Continue" class="ml1">
  </div>
  <div id="error" style="color: red"></div>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="nowrap text-left" colspan="2">Section 1</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>A1.</td>
        <td class="nowrap form-radio"><label>
                                                        <input name="CriteriaA1" type="radio" value="Yes"><span>Yes</span></label><label class="ml3"><input name="CriteriaA1" type="radio" value="No"><span>No</span></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A2.</td>
        <td class="nowrap form-radio"><label>
                                                        <input name="CriteriaA2" type="radio" value="Yes"><span>Yes</span></label><label class="ml3"><input name="CriteriaA2" type="radio" value="No"><span>No</span></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A3.</td>
        <td class="nowrap form-radio"><label>
                                                        <input name="CriteriaA3" type="radio" value="Yes"><span>Yes</span></label><label class="ml3"><input name="CriteriaA3" type="radio" value="No"><span>No</span></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A4.</td>
        <td class="nowrap form-radio"><label>
                                                        <input name="CriteriaA4" type="radio" value="Yes"><span>Yes</span></label><label class="ml3"><input name="CriteriaA4" type="radio" value="No"><span>No</span></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A5.</td>
        <td class="nowrap form-radio"><label>
                                                        <input name="CriteriaA5" type="radio" value="Yes"><span>Yes</span></label><label class="ml3"><input name="CriteriaA5" type="radio" value="No"><span>No</span></label></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <p class="m2"><strong>OR</strong></p>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="nowrap text-left" colspan="2">Section 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>B1. </td>
        <td class="nowrap form-radio"><label>
                                                        <input name="CriteriaB1" type="radio" value="Yes"><span>Yes</span></label><label class="ml3"><input name="CriteriaB1" type="radio" value="No"><span>No</span></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>B2.</td>
        <td class="nowrap form-radio"><label>
                                                        <input name="CriteriaB2" type="radio" value="Yes"><span>Yes</span></label><label class="ml3"><input name="CriteriaB2" type="radio" value="No"><span>No</span></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>B3.</td>
        <td class="nowrap form-radio"><label>
                                                        <input name="CriteriaB3" type="radio" value="Yes"><span>Yes</span></label><label class="ml3"><input name="CriteriaB3" type="radio" value="No"><span>No</span></label></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <p class="m2"><strong>OR</strong></p>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="nowrap text-left" colspan="2">Section 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>C1.</td>
        <td class="nowrap form-radio"><label>
                                                        <input name="CriteriaC1" type="radio" value="Yes"><span>Yes</span></label><label class="ml3"><input name="CriteriaC1" type="radio" value="No"><span>No</span></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C2.</td>
        <td class="nowrap form-radio"><label>
                                                        <input name="CriteriaC2" type="radio" value="Yes"><span>Yes</span></label><label class="ml3"><input name="CriteriaC2" type="radio" value="No"><span>No</span></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C3. </td>
        <td class="nowrap form-radio"><label>
                                                        <input name="CriteriaC3" type="radio" value="Yes"><span>Yes</span></label><label class="ml3"><input name="CriteriaC3" type="radio" value="No"><span>No</span></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C4. </td>
        <td class="nowrap form-radio"><label>
                                                        <input name="CriteriaC4" type="radio" value="Yes"><span>Yes</span></label><label class="ml3"><input name="CriteriaC4" type="radio" value="No"><span>No</span></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C5. </td>
        <td class="nowrap form-radio"><label>
                                                        <input name="CriteriaC5" type="radio" value="Yes"><span>Yes</span></label><label class="ml3"><input name="CriteriaC5" type="radio" value="No"><span>No</span></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C6. </td>
        <td class="nowrap form-radio"><label>
                                                <input name="CriteriaC6" type="radio" value="Yes"><span>Yes</span></label><label class="ml3"><input name="CriteriaC6" type="radio" value="No"><span>No</span></label></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


  <div class="rate-buttons left py2">
    <input type="reset" name="buttonType" value="Reset" class="mx1">
    <input type="submit" name="buttonType" id="submit" value="Continue" class="ml1">
  </div>
  <div id="error" style="color: red"></div>

  <!-- to here -->

</form>
```

I'm not sure how to check for "no" answers when the Continue button if clicked and then show a dialog box if they are?

Comment: If the user is only allowed to use one section you should hide the other sections once the user choses a section. By doing that your JS will have less clutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the value of each field to verify if it's "**Yes**" or "**No**"

```
inputs[name] = $("input[name='"+name+"']:checked").val() || false;
```

Then simply create an array with the values and finally check if all values are "**No**" using `every` function.
Below is a working demo.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#editRecord").on("submit", function (e) {
        var buttonClicked = $("input[type=submit][clicked=true]").val();

        if (buttonClicked === "Continue") {
          if (!validateFinish(e)) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("Continue");
          }
        } else if (buttonClicked === "Save Draft") {
          if (!validateSaveDraft()) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("Save Draft");
          }
        }
      });

      $("input[type=submit]").click(function () {
        $("input[type=submit]", $(this).parents("form")).removeAttr("clicked");
        $(this).attr("clicked", "true");
      });

      function validateFinish(ev) {
        // Add your validation logic for the Finish button here
        //alert("Form Validation is starting!");

        var sectionsTouched = $("tbody").has(":checked"),
          inputs = {},
          errorMessage = "";

        if (sectionsTouched.length === 0) {
          errorMessage = "Please check something before submitting.";
        } else if (sectionsTouched.length > 1) {
          errorMessage = "Please complete A or B or C only";
        } else {
          sectionsTouched.find("input").each(function (i, e) {
            var me = $(e),
              name = me.attr("name");
            inputs[name] = $("input[name='"+name+"']:checked").val() || false;
          });

          $.each(inputs, function (k, v) {
            if (!v) {
              errorMessage = "It appears you have not completed all questions.";
            }
            return v;
          });

          var isAllNo = Object.values(inputs).every(function(q){
              return q === 'No'
          });

          if(isAllNo){
            if (confirm('You have selected "No" for your answers. Do you wish to continue?')) {
              console.log('Thing was saved to the database.');
            } else {
              console.log('Thing was not saved to the database.');
              ev.preventDefault();
            }          
          }
        }
        if (errorMessage !== "") {
          $("#error").html(errorMessage);
          ev.preventDefault();
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      }

      function validateSaveDraft() {
        // Add your validation logic for the Save Draft button here
        //alert("Just saving a Draft!");
        return true;
      }
    });
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <form action="rateArticleCodes.php" method="post" class="" id="editRecord">
    <input type="hidden" name="recid" value="123445" />

    <div class="rate-buttons left py2">
      <input
        type="submit"
        name="buttonType"
        id="saveDraft"
        value="Save Draft"
        class="mr1"
      />
      <input type="reset" name="buttonType" value="Reset" class="mx1" />
      <input
        type="submit"
        name="buttonType"
        id="submit"
        value="Continue"
        class="ml1"
      />
    </div>
    <div id="error" style="color: red"></div>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="nowrap text-left" colspan="2">Section 1</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>A1.</td>
          <td class="nowrap form-radio">
            <label>
              <input name="CriteriaA1" type="radio" value="Yes" /><span
                >Yes</span
              ></label
            ><label class="ml3"
              ><input name="CriteriaA1" type="radio" value="No" /><span
                >No</span
              ></label
            >
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A2.</td>
          <td class="nowrap form-radio">
            <label>
              <input name="CriteriaA2" type="radio" value="Yes" /><span
                >Yes</span
              ></label
            ><label class="ml3"
              ><input name="CriteriaA2" type="radio" value="No" /><span
                >No</span
              ></label
            >
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A3.</td>
          <td class="nowrap form-radio">
            <label>
              <input name="CriteriaA3" type="radio" value="Yes" /><span
                >Yes</span
              ></label
            ><label class="ml3"
              ><input name="CriteriaA3" type="radio" value="No" /><span
                >No</span
              ></label
            >
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A4.</td>
          <td class="nowrap form-radio">
            <label>
              <input name="CriteriaA4" type="radio" value="Yes" /><span
                >Yes</span
              ></label
            ><label class="ml3"
              ><input name="CriteriaA4" type="radio" value="No" /><span
                >No</span
              ></label
            >
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A5.</td>
          <td class="nowrap form-radio">
            <label>
              <input name="CriteriaA5" type="radio" value="Yes" /><span
                >Yes</span
              ></label
            ><label class="ml3"
              ><input name="CriteriaA5" type="radio" value="No" /><span
                >No</span
              ></label
            >
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <p class="m2"><strong>OR</strong></p>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="nowrap text-left" colspan="2">Section 2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>B1.</td>
          <td class="nowrap form-radio">
            <label>
              <input name="CriteriaB1" type="radio" value="Yes" /><span
                >Yes</span
              ></label
            ><label class="ml3"
              ><input name="CriteriaB1" type="radio" value="No" /><span
                >No</span
              ></label
            >
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>B2.</td>
          <td class="nowrap form-radio">
            <label>
              <input name="CriteriaB2" type="radio" value="Yes" /><span
                >Yes</span
              ></label
            ><label class="ml3"
              ><input name="CriteriaB2" type="radio" value="No" /><span
                >No</span
              ></label
            >
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>B3.</td>
          <td class="nowrap form-radio">
            <label>
              <input name="CriteriaB3" type="radio" value="Yes" /><span
                >Yes</span
              ></label
            ><label class="ml3"
              ><input name="CriteriaB3" type="radio" value="No" /><span
                >No</span
              ></label
            >
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <p class="m2"><strong>OR</strong></p>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="nowrap text-left" colspan="2">Section 3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>C1.</td>
          <td class="nowrap form-radio">
            <label>
              <input name="CriteriaC1" type="radio" value="Yes" /><span
                >Yes</span
              ></label
            ><label class="ml3"
              ><input name="CriteriaC1" type="radio" value="No" /><span
                >No</span
              ></label
            >
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>C2.</td>
          <td class="nowrap form-radio">
            <label>
              <input name="CriteriaC2" type="radio" value="Yes" /><span
                >Yes</span
              ></label
            ><label class="ml3"
              ><input name="CriteriaC2" type="radio" value="No" /><span
                >No</span
              ></label
            >
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>C3.</td>
          <td class="nowrap form-radio">
            <label>
              <input name="CriteriaC3" type="radio" value="Yes" /><span
                >Yes</span
              ></label
            ><label class="ml3"
              ><input name="CriteriaC3" type="radio" value="No" /><span
                >No</span
              ></label
            >
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>C4.</td>
          <td class="nowrap form-radio">
            <label>
              <input name="CriteriaC4" type="radio" value="Yes" /><span
                >Yes</span
              ></label
            ><label class="ml3"
              ><input name="CriteriaC4" type="radio" value="No" /><span
                >No</span
              ></label
            >
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>C5.</td>
          <td class="nowrap form-radio">
            <label>
              <input name="CriteriaC5" type="radio" value="Yes" /><span
                >Yes</span
              ></label
            ><label class="ml3"
              ><input name="CriteriaC5" type="radio" value="No" /><span
                >No</span
              ></label
            >
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>C6.</td>
          <td class="nowrap form-radio">
            <label>
              <input name="CriteriaC6" type="radio" value="Yes" /><span
                >Yes</span
              ></label
            ><label class="ml3"
              ><input name="CriteriaC6" type="radio" value="No" /><span
                >No</span
              ></label
            >
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="rate-buttons left py2">
      <input type="reset" name="buttonType" value="Reset" class="mx1" />
      <input
        type="submit"
        name="buttonType"
        id="submit"
        value="Continue"
        class="ml1"
      />
    </div>
    <div id="error" style="color: red"></div>

    <!-- to here -->
  </form>
```